# Select box puts dotted rectangle on mouse select

Tags: javascript, css

My select box puts a dotted rectangle, when i do mouse select in it. How can i clear this?

[image]

I saw many people having this same issue, and taking their inputs, i updated my css with these properties, but of no use.

```
select::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
select{
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
  margin: 10em 10em;
}    
select::-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

I am using Firefox 38.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Try adding !important to the end of each style?

Comment: nope, it din't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the css properties for both `select` and `option` tags removed the dotted lines finally....

```
select::-moz-focus-inner, option::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
select, option{
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
  margin: 10em 10em;
}    
select::-moz-focusring, option::-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 black;
}
```